# How can I make a ring in JavaFX (fxml)

Tags: java, javafx, geometry, fill, fxml

I need to make a ring in JavaFX using fxml.  It will be circling an item on an image beneath it.  I can make a circle, but it seems to be required to have a fill.  I can adjust the opacity, but that adjusts the opacity of both the fill and the circle.

I don't have image editing software at work (and I can't just install gimp) so I can't create an image and use an ImageView.  Paint won't let you save images without backgrounds.

It seems like such a simple task to create a circle without a fill.  Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the `Arc` (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Arc.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the circle for that, just make sure to add this in your CSS:

```css
 .circle {
 /* The numbers before the alpha doesn't matter.  
    As you imagine this would be green if the alpha was higher
    rgba(RED,GREEN,BLUE,ALPHA); RGBA
 */ 
         -fx-fill:  rgba(0,255,0,0);

 }
```

if you want to have other circles you can specify an specific css class for this:

```css
 .ring {
      -fx-fill:  rgba(0,255,0,0);
 }
```

Then:

```
circle.getStyleClass().add("ring");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fill with color.TRANSPARENT and stroke with color you want.

Answer (score 0):

Or, following the same idea as Mansueli, use this programmatically:

```
circle.setFill(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```